# How to include external JS lib in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm actually building an app using ionic and Cordova. I got a library, that I want to use in my app.
It is an external JS lib, and I don't know how to include it in my project : [Git-Hub](https://github.com/mulesoft/js-client-oauth2)
Surely into lib folder and how to include the code & Controller & js file and How to call it ?

Cheers..

Comment: If that library is in npm you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Answer (score 1):

The library you mentioned supports bower, so I would suggest going to your application directory, then run (in a cmd):

```
bower install client-oauth2 --save
```

It then installs the library in www/lib.

Then go to your index.html and just include the js file:

```
<!-- include this library before your app.js and other files you're using it -->
<script src="lib/client-oauth2/client-oauth2.js></script>
```

Comment: It's ok, but then, how can I use this lib in my app.js file with controller for example. I got clientid, clientsecret,acccestokenuri and redirecturi, but I don't know how to test my api with these informations

Comment: In combination with angular I would suggest grabbing a library that is specifically created for angular, like https://github.com/oauthjs/angular-oauth2

Comment: Ok, I'm going to test it

Comment: It looks fine, but then, how can I use it with my login form (username, password and submit button) ?

Comment: I tried https://github.com/oauthjs/angular-oauth2 but there is no get method to get dats from the api